# Using Select and Where parameter = any\dontcare in MySQL with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

In my MySQL based C# code  I have to implement and Search filter on my database, so I have written a select * from table where (list of parameter conditions);
The problem is that sometimes I want the default "Select all" for a particular parameter. Like 
select * from table where type=(any\don't care);

I want all the different rows with all the types shown without filtering. The same case as it would happen if I had omitted that where clause; I cant omit the where clause in mine cause the structure of my query will get broken . . the whole extra or missing "and" cause im using string builder to concatenate the query. Ill post my code below incase someone has a better way of doing this;

```
        str.Append("Select * From ");
        str.Append(" recording ");
        str.Append(" WHERE ");



        switch (type)
        {
            case "Audio": str.Append(" and Type = " + 1 + " ");
                break;
            case "Video": str.Append(" and Type = " + 2 + " ");
                break;
            case "VoIP": str.Append(" and Type = " + 3 + " ");
                break;
            default: <**SUGGESTION HERE**> 
                break;
        }

        if (!(channelname == ""))
        {
            str.Append("and ChannelName = '" + channelname + "' ");
        }

        if(!(channel == "All"))
        {
            str.Append(" and ChannelId = '" + channel + "' ");
        }



        if (archive == "true")
        {
            str.Append(" and Archive = " + true + " ");
        }
        else if (archive == "false")
        {
            str.Append(" and Archive = " + true + " ");
        }

        str.Append(" and StartTime > '" + from + "' and ");

        str.Append("StartTime < '" + to + "' ");
        if (duration > 0)
        {
            str.Append(" and (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,EndTime,StartTime))" + durationtype + " " + duration);
        }

        str.Append(" ;");
        sqltext = str.ToString();
```

Here, If u can suggest a statement in the switch statement which can display all the types something which has logic equivalent to "type=anything" that would do the trick. And I kno "Type in (1,2,3, etc)" . . but these fields are user creatable so many will come up later I wanted a general solution and also I kno I can use another select statement inside like "type in (select bla bla)" . . I just wanted to kno if MySQL Supports a generic value for parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change like this

```
str.Append(" WHERE 1=1 ");
```

now rest of your query can remain the same. Your query will become some thing like this

```
select * from yourTable where 1=1 and condition1 and condition2 ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The classic solution in building sql queries is (`WHERE 1=1`) which comes out as true for every row.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding 1=1 with where

```
    str.Append("Select * From ");
    str.Append(" recording ");
    str.Append(" WHERE 1=1 ");



    switch (type)
    {
        case "Audio": str.Append(" and Type = " + 1 + " ");
            break;
        case "Video": str.Append(" and Type = " + 2 + " ");
            break;
        case "VoIP": str.Append(" and Type = " + 3 + " ");
            break;
    }
```